# toFixed javascript function giving strange results?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to fix the number to 2 digits after decimal and for that i am using `toFixed`function of javascript. Below are the strange results i am getting, please check and help me.

```
var number = 11.995;
number.toFixed(2); // giving me 11.99 which is correct

var number = 19.995;
number.toFixed(2); // giving me 20.00 which is incorrect
```

Can anyone tell me why it is happening.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how floating point math works. The value 19.995 is not exact binary (base 2). To make it more clear, think of an exact number when you divide 10/3.

For more in-depth explanations, read this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

In your case you can work with strings instead (at least it seems like that is what you want):

```
number.toString().substr(0, n);
```

Or define a function like this (made in 2 minutes, just an example):

```
Number.toFixed = function(no, n) {
    var spl = no.toString().split('.');
    if ( spl.length > 1 ) {
        return spl[0]+'.'+spl[1].substr(0,n);
    }
    return spl[0];
}

Number.toFixed(19.995, 2); // 19.99
```

Comment: @RobW correct, but it was not meant to be an exact replacement just in theory. But thanks!

Comment: 0,4 only gives 1 decimal in this case. You'd better use `indexOf` to detect the dot, or just use a RegExp for a one-liner: `/-?\d+(\.\d{0,2})?/`. Note: The regexp is not complete, it doesn't deal with exponents.

Answer (score 2):

I have create a function which done all for me..

```
    function toFixed(number, precision) {
        var multiplier = Math.pow(10, precision + 1),
            wholeNumber = Math.floor(number * multiplier);
        return Math.round(wholeNumber / 10) * 10 / multiplier;
    }

   //Call this function to retrive exect value
    toFixed((+adjustmentval), 2);
```

Comment: My thoughts exactly!  Too bad `toFixed` doesn't do that - how are we supposed to know there might be a problem?  Well, I guess that we should be aware(?)...

Answer (score 1):

`toFixed` rounds the value. Since 19.995 is exactly halfway between 19.99 and 20.00, it has to choose one of them. Traditionally, rounding prefers the even result (this prevents bias, since round-ups and round-downs will be equal).

Comment: It doesn’t "choose". 19.995 is not *exactly* halfway, since floating numbers are not exact in javascript. You can test this by adding `19.999991 + 0.000004` wich equals `19.999995000000002`.

Comment: Some floating point fractions are exact, though, such as 0.5. However, it looks like I was wrong about it rounding to even, it always rounds up. `0.5.toFixed(0)` is 1, `1.5.toFixed(0)` is 2.

Comment: No it doesn’t always round up, and that was the original question. F.ex `(11.995).toFixed(2)` is 11.99

Comment: That's because of what you said earlier, that it isn't exact. The one that are exactly halfway round up.

Answer (score 0):

David has answered your doubt I'm guessing. Just providing an alternate solution here.

You can use the `Math.floor()` method of the Math object for this.

Something like this, `Math.floor(number*100)/100`

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone tell me why it is happening.

The [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) double-precision binary floating point number standard used by JavaScript's `number` type (and similar times in several other languages) does not perfectly store all numbers, it stores some numbers *imprecisely*, in a way that lets it A) Store them in just 64 bits, and B) Calculate with them quickly.

For `11.995`, the actual value is `11.99499988555908203125`, just slightly ***less*** than `11.995`.

For `19.995`, the actual value is `19.9950008392333984375`, just slightly ***more*** than `19.995`.

That explains why when you round them using the usual round-to-nearest-half-up operation, `11.995` (which is really `11.99499988555908203125`) rounds down to `11.99` but `19.995` (which is really `19.9950008392333984375`) rounds up to `20.00`.

*([This site](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) has a handy calculator for visualizing this stuff.)*

More here on SO:

- [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)
- [How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript)