# Why toFixed() rounding is so strange

Tags: javascript

Chrome 29.0.1547.57:

```
0.0095 .toFixed(3) // "0.009"
0.1095 .toFixed(3) // "0.110"
1.1095 .toFixed(3) // "1.109"
```

What's wrong with this function?
I know that I can write my own function, the question here is why stock function is so buggy?
According to MDN it was implemented in JS 1.5 so it's not new. Or maybe I don't understand this function right?

Comment: Buggy may not be the most appropriate word to describe how `toFixed` works, it's just how floating pointer numbers work, which might not be expected.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105787/tofixed-javascript-function-giving-strange-results

Comment: If you thinking floating point numbers and *rounding* is buggy, wait till you deal with code that mixes floating point numbers and financial transactions.

Comment: `Intl.NumberFormat` rounding is not so strange, it could be used wherever num.isFixed() is used. see [Formatting a number with exactly two decimals in js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726630/formatting-a-number-with-exactly-two-decimals-in-javascript/1726662#1726662)

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that binary floating point representation of most decimal fractions is not exact. The internal representation of `0.0095` may actually be something like `0.00949999`, so `toFixed` rounds down, while `0.1095` might be `0.109500001`, which rounds up.

See [Javascript toFixed Not Rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10015027/javascript-tofixed-not-rounding)