# Convert bytes to TB returns incorrect value

Tags: javascript

Currently I have a function to convert bytes too TB.

I am using the below formula to convert.

```js
const formatBytesToTB = (a, b = 2) => {
  if (a === 0) {
    return "0 TB";
  }
  return (a / 1099511627776).toFixed(b) + " TB";
};
console.log(formatBytesToTB(109213384704));
```

The above function is working fine for most of the values that it accepts as bytes

I see some error when bytes value is less than 1 TB.

For example when the input is "109213384704” the function returns “0.10 TB”

**Expected output should be “0.09”**

I have seen few online converters to test what they return, Google returns 0.10 but rest of the converters show 0.09

Is the function doing right thing ?

Comment: Technically, it should be `0.099` if I'm not wrong. What about using `.toPrecision` instead of `.toFixed`?

Comment: Increase `b` to be bigger, like 10 and see then. Seems like rounding problem

Comment: toFixed is doing the right thing, since the number is 0.099 but you wanted only the first 2 digits so 0.099 is rounded up to 0.10 to account for the x.xx9 that it couldn't display - if you want truncation rather than rounding, pretty sure that could be done with a little toString+substring trickery, though

Comment: more info about strange behaviour of toFixed can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105787/tofixed-javascript-function-giving-strange-results) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490687/broken-tofixed-implementation)

Comment: Good answers can also be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript)

Comment: You want TB, but calculate with TiB. 1 TiB == 1099511627776 Bytes, 1 TB == 1000000000000 Bytes.

Answer (score 1):

`109213384704` is 0.099 In `Tebibyte`(TiB) and 0.10 `Terrabyte` (TB).

From [definitions](https://searchstorage.techtarget.com/definition/tebibyte-TiB):

How large is a tebibyte?
A tebibyte is larger than the following binary data capacity measures:

- A byte -- a TiB is equal to 1,099,511,627,776 bytes.
- A kibibyte (KiB) -- a TiB is equal to 1,073,741,824 KiB.
- A mebibyte (MiB) – a TiB is equal to 1,048,576 MiB.
- A gibibyte -- a TiB is equal to 1,024 GiB.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a matter of display -  Rounding vs Ignoring the decimal after precision value.

The value of `109213384704 / 1099511627776` is `0.099328995`

So if you would like to simply ignore whatever comes after the second decimal point, you'll get `0.09`.

However,`toFixed` will round the number to the precision value, so `0.099` will result `0.10` while `0.091` will result with `0.09`.

Comment: I want to round off to 2 decimal places but still return accurate result, I dont think toPrecision also works. Is there any other alternative ?

Comment: The current behavior is the more accurate option, as  `0.099` is closer to `0.10` then to `0.09`. In this regard, it makes no different if you use `toPrecision` or `toFixed`