# 0.15 is not getting converted t 0.2 in javascript using tofixed function?

Tags: javascript

My javascript code is:

```js
var a = 0.15;
var r = parseFloat(a.toFixed(1));
console.log(r)
```

This is not getting converted to `0.2`.

Whereas other numbers like `0.25` are getting converted to `0.3`,
`0.45` to `0.5`, `0.55` to `0.6`, `0.65` to `0.7`, `0.85` to `0.9` and so on.

Any solution to resolve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Round to at most 2 decimal places (only if necessary)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-only-if-necessary), you just need to change it to 1 decimal

Comment: can u plz provide syntax for the same ?

Comment: read the linked question and you find your question answered

Comment: `0.35` will be `"0.3"` and `0.85` will be `"0.9"` - at least in Chrome und Firefox ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c87yoxqb/))

Comment: MDN has called out it might round up or down: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed#Description What's your goal? Are you trying to round to 1 decimal point? Maybe use `(Math.round(0.15 * 10)/10).toFixed(1)` instead?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105787/tofixed-javascript-function-giving-strange-results#
Check in this post behaviour is explained.

Comment: @Chuanqi Sun  Can u plz explain the logic behind this ?             
                 (Math.round(0.15 * 10)/10).toFixed(1)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because floating point representation cannot be exact for some numbers.

You can use a library such as [Big.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js/) that has arbitrary precision to compute such values.

```js
var a = Big("0.15");
console.log(a.toFixed(1));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/big-js@3.1.3/big.js"></script>
```