# Why .toFixed not same working if difference value?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to round a float value to a float with 1 digit after decimal point.

```
const value_1 = 58.65;
const value_2 = 58.25;

const round = (v) => {
  return parseFloat((v).toFixed(1));
}

console.log(round(value_1), round(value_2));
```

Above code, It's print 2 value are 58.6 and 58.3

Why value_1 after round equal 58.6, that not is 58.7

Comment: Does this answer your question?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10015027/javascript-tofixed-not-rounding

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105787/tofixed-javascript-function-giving-strange-results